# footer in magento theme glitches only in product

Tags: javascript, php, css, magento, footer

Footer works great in homepage -> http://www.matildabytruelove.com/tiendea/index.php/

But it crops in product description (the specific problem)
http://www.matildabytruelove.com/tiendea/index.php/m-swb146144.html

Already flushed magento cache and css/java and submitted all blocks. Cant reproduce error.

js and css is the same that this one -> lomalo.com.mx/tiendea/index.php/prueba-001.html (the desired behavior)

But footer just fails to load properly.

any idea of what is messing around with the footer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include an [mcve], which is a) the desired behavior, b) the *specific problem or error* you're seeing and c) the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce your error

Comment: Edited.

Cant put more than 2 links. I got the example of what I want  lomalo.com.mx/tiendea/index.php/prueba-001.html 

and is working (desired behavior)

Specific problem -> footer crops in product description http://www.matildabytruelove.com/tiendea/index.php/m-swb146144.html


Cant reproduce the error sin dont know wich one is.

Answer (score 0):

your product page class="main container" div close before

```
<div class="our-features-box wow bounceInUp animated animated" style="visibility: visible;"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

for more info please see link [see in console html structure](http://prntscr.com/7yity6)

Comment: Indeed main container was closing before <footer> fixed that and still crops ->http://www.matildabytruelove.com/tiendea/index.php/m-swb146144.html

Comment: please check in screenshot and follow same html structure.place your div which have class "our-feature-box" and footer outside of  "main container" div.